# TypeScript: How to pass null to an overloaded function in versions after 0.8.0.0?

Tags: null, arguments, overloading, typescript

Updated TypeScript from 0.8.0.0 to 0.8.1.1 today. The TS compiler now complains about passing `null` or `undefined` to a function/method that is overloaded.

For example, the google maps `Marker` class has a `setMap` method with 2 overloads. This is taken from the [google maps definition file in the Definitely Typed project](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/googlemaps/google.maps.d.ts):

```
declare module google.maps {
    ...
    export class Marker extends MVCObject {
        ...
        setMap(map: Map): void;
        setMap(map: StreetViewPanorama): void;
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

[According to the google maps API v3 docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Marker), to remove a marker from a map, you should set its map to null. I previously had this with TS 0.8.0.0 and it worked fine:

```
var someMarker: google.maps.Marker = (code to initialize marker);
...
someMarker.setMap(null);
```

TypeScript 0.8.1.1 complains about this with the message:

> Ambiguous call expression - could not choose overload.

One fix I tried that did not work was trying to coerce TS into believing `null` was a reference to a `google.maps.Map`. This is apparently incorrect syntax, as the compiler complains it expects a `;` where the `)` is.

```
someMarker.setMap(null: google.maps.Map);
```

Here is the fix I have now, which seems to work. **Is this the right way to work around this issue?**

```
var nullMap: google.maps.Map = null;
someMarker.setMap(nullMap);
```

I realize another fix could be to modify the google maps TS definition file to allow an overload of `setMap(map: any): void;`, but that seems like a bad solution. **Is there any other way currently, or planned in future TS builds, to work around this?**

Comment: This is a bug - http://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/587. I believe it will be fixed in either 0.8.2.0 or 0.8.3.0. Peter Olson's suggestion below is the best workaround.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way you are working around it now works, but is more verbose than necessary.

You can specify that you mean `null` to be of the type `google.maps.Map` by casting it as such.

```
someMarker.setMap(<google.maps.Map>null);
```

Comment: Thanks for the cast syntax, I was unaware of this.

Comment: As of now, the [preferred](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/type-assertion.html) syntax for type _assertions_ (we are not technically _casting_ anything here, after all) is `null as google.maps.Map`.

Answer (score 0):

I tried

```
someMarker.setMap(<google.maps.Map>null);
```

as suggested, but it didn't work. I got this compile error: `Type 'null' cannot be converted to type 'Map'.`

Here is the way that worked for me:

```
interface GenericMapShimType {
  setMap(map: google.maps.Map | null): void;
}
(someMarker as SetMapShimType).setMap(null);
```